# Call validate function along with submit data function on button click

Tags: asp.net

I want to validate a code, and if it is correct than send the data on page to DB.

Here are the functions:

```
ValidateCode(object send, EventArgs e)
{ logic here}
```

And the submit button code:

```
Register_Clicked(object sen, EventArgs e)
```

So within the Register click I want to fire the `ValidateCode` function and if it is correct than only save data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure your ValidateCode() function returns a boolean value (true if validation is passed; false otherwise):

```
ValidateCode(object send, EventArgs e)
{ 
    // logic here

    // return boolean value
    if (passed) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then you can add this in your register_clicked function:

```
 Register_Clicked(object send, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (ValidateCode(send, e)) {
         // validation passed code
     } else {
         // validation failed code
     }
 }
```

Comment: what if I have got validation messages in validatecode(sender, e) function .. how can I display those messages in this functioin `Register_Clicked`